# Map iterator no match for operator

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I have no match for operator in `map` iterator. When I try to make the iterator it points to the map end-1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
int main()
{
    std::map<char,int> mymap;

    mymap['b'] = 100;
    mymap['a'] = 200;
    mymap['c'] = 300;

    // show content:
    for (std::map<char,int>::iterator it=mymap.begin(); it!=mymap.end()-1; ++it){
        std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you re-phrase your question? It isn't exactly clear what the issue is. An exception message or example problematic output would be helpful.

Comment: You cannot add or subtract anything from a map iterator. `mymap.end()-1` is illegal. Map iterators don't work this way.

Answer (score 2):

This statement

```
mymap.end()-1
```

is only legal for [Random Access Iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) but `std::map::iterator` is [Bidirectional Iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator). If you want to skip last element use `std::prev()`

```
for (std::map<char,int>::iterator it=mymap.begin(); it!=std::prev( mymap.end() ); ++it)
```

though it is not efficient to always calculate it and it should be instead:

```
 auto end = std::prev( mymap.end() );
 for (auto it=mymap.begin(); it!=end; ++it) ...
```

Note for this to work you have to be sure that there is at least one element in your map. If you do not want to skip the last element remove `-1` completely.

Answer (score 0):

There's no operator- for map iterators, but it doesn't matter because if you want to show all the content is should be just `it!=mymap.end();`